# Train on Specificity

Tags: r, r-caret

I use Caret to train my model (binary classification task). How can I make sure that train() doesn't train on the accuracy metric, but on Specificity (TN / (TN+FP)) metric?

what works on Accuracy:

```
control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10) 
metric <- "Accuracy"

set.seed(7) 
fit.svm <- train(target_var ~., data=dataset, method="svmRadial", metric=metric, trControl=control)
```

It doesn't work to change:

```
metric = "Specificity"
```

Does anyone know how to train the model to optimise the Specificity?

KR, 
Arnand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifiyng the `summaryFunction` argument to `twoClassSummary` inside `trainControl` along with `classProbs = TRUE` , and `metric = "Spec"` inside `train()`:

```
control <- trainControl(method="cv", 
                        number=10, 
                        summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                        classProbs = TRUE) 

fit.svm <- train(target_var ~., 
                 data=dataset,
                 method="svmRadial", 
                 metric="Spec", 
                 trControl=control)
```

Comment: Thank, if I use your function I get: 
'Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , lvls[1]) : undefined columns selected'

If I replace 'trControl' with 'trainControl' it works, but I get the Warning measure:
Warning message:
In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
  The metric "Spec" was not in the result set. Accuracy will be used instead.

Comment: see edit, you probably need `classProbs = TRUE` inside `trainControl()`, and dataset needs to be a data.frame.

Comment: A bit late to the game but I am getting the same warning `Warning message:
In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : The metric "Spec" was not in the result set. Accuracy will be used instead.` - Any ideas on how to fix this? I have `classProbs = TRUE` set in `trainControl` to no avail.